# Как синхронизировать локальную папку на Amazon S3?

Tags: файлы, синхронизация, linux

На CentOS сервере крутится Wordpress, и принимает аплоады медиа файлов в некую папку.Надо синхронизировать её в букет на [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), т.к. именно оттуда файлы раздаются посетителям сайта.

1. Первая попытка, по-простому: с помощью [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) и [S3FS](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) букет монировался как устройство, и на файлы загружались прямо в него. Оказалось, плохо: медленно, и часто случались ошибки обработки загружаемых файлов.
2. Второй шаг: стали держать локальную папку, в которую происходит загрузка; её с помощью [lsyncd](http://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/) синхронизировали в смонтированный S3 букет. Лучше, но иногда происходят случайные, неуловимые ошибки, и некоторые файлы не проходят, оказываясь в букете с нулевым размером. И позже, эти нулевые файлы так и не обновляются до полноразмерной версии.

Поэтому сейчас в поисках "третьего" варианта. Как синхронизировать аплоады, с минимальным лэгом, и с бетонной надёжностью, с локальной папки в букет на Амазоне?

Подвохи:

1. удалённая FS смонтированного S3 букета работает далеко не мгновенно, копирование одного mp3 может занять неск. секунд;
2. в момент синхронизации некоторые файлы могут быть открыты — скажем, их сейчас прямо кто-то догружает на сервер, или картинки уменьшаются и записываются их уменьшенные копии.

Answer (score 1):

[Ответ](http://habrahabr.ru/qa/34715/) на этот же вопрос на Хабре